# dblink.sql is not present after postgresql-contrib install

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos

I was able to successfully install postgresql-contrib onto one of my servers and shortly after I had executed dblink.sql onto two of my Postgres databases. After installing postgresql-contrib, I found dblink.sql at the following location:

```
/usr/share/pgsql/contrib/dblink.sql
```

Now, I'm trying to do the same thing on another server. After installing postgresql-contrib however, I cannot find any instance of db.sql. Both servers are running CentOS 6.2 and PostgreSQL 9.1, although the PostgreSQL installation on the second server is located in another directory:

```
PGENGINE=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin
PGPORT=5432
PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data
PGLOG=/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/pgstartup.log
```

When I do "locate dblink", I receive the following:

```
[root@dev-postgres dblink]# locate dblink
/usr/lib/debug/usr/pgsql-9.1/lib/dblink.so.debug
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_build_sql_delete.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_build_sql_insert.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_build_sql_update.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_cancel_query.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_close.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_connect.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_connect_u.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_disconnect.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_error_message.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_exec.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_fetch.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_get_connections.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_get_notify.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_get_pkey.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_get_result.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_is_busy.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_open.3
/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/man/man3/dblink_send_query.3
/usr/src/debug/postgresql-9.1.4/contrib/dblink
/usr/src/debug/postgresql-9.1.4/contrib/dblink/dblink.c
```

...with no dblink.sql. Does anyone know what I can do here? Do I have to somehow build the sql file? If so, do you know how I might do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be bundled as an extension in 9.1

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib.html

Comment: I do have dblink--1.0.sql, dblink--unpackaged--1.0.sql, and dblink.control in /usr/pgsql-9.1/share/extension - does that just mean I need to run CREATE EXTENSION dblink; on my database? Do I need to somehow point it to that path?

Comment: Just try CREATE EXTENSION as described in the manuals. It should know which scripts to run.

Comment: Great, that worked without any problems. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just as a note, the shift to the extension system in 9.1 is a much needed change, but it causes a lot of headaches for many people actually trying to support multiple versions of PostgreSQL while relying on contrib modules.  We have struggled with this on LedgerSMB 1.3 for months.

A lot of stuff can change between major versions of the software.  I highly recommend following the release notes in major versions *carefully* before updating or just assuming everything will be the same.  These are long, complicated documents but they ought to give you an idea of where you will run into problems and where you need to further check the new docs.  If you are testing a deployment first (always a good idea!) it will also give you a much better idea of where to spend extra effort testing.